# Pseudocode/Java basic array summing algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, methods, sum, pseudocode

I just had this question on an final exam for an introductory CS course. I thought it was pretty interesting but I couldn't fully figure it out. I tried coding it out on Eclipse for a while and wasn't getting anywhere. I have a Biochem exam soon so I really should be studying for that but this is bugging me... Thought I would ask for help.

Question -- Write an algorithm for the following: 
Given an input array, A, with 2 indices -- start and stop -- calculate the sum between the two. The array is sorted and all elements belong to the set {1, 2, 3}. This algorithm must run in O(log(n)). So given an array {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3} with indices 1 and 5 it would return 11.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int findSum(int[] a, int start, int stop) {

    int sum = 0;

    int temp[] = new int[4];
    int mid = (start+stop)/2;

    while (mid > start || mid < stop) {

        if (a[mid+1]-a[mid] != 0) {
            temp[mid+1] = mid+1;
            temp[mid] = mid;
            mid++;
        }
        else {
            findSum(a, start, mid);
            findSum(a, mid+1, stop);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        if (temp[i] == 0) {
            temp[i] = temp[i-1];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        sum += i*(temp[i]-temp[i-1]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Don't know if my logic is correct at all but my idea was to look for indices in the array where the numbers shift and to do so in a recursive manner where I keep splitting the array into two parts. With these indices, I can determine the frequency in which the numbers appear and thus multiply the numbers by these frequencies and add those up to calculate the sum.

Pretty sure my algorithm has numerous flaws in it...

Comment: Are you sure this question wasn't about a *search* algorithm? Namely the [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). When you add everything in an array range, you're going to have an O(n) operation anyhow: you'll inevitably have to calculate for every number in the range. Since the array is already sorted, I'm already more confident that that's what the question was asking for (for you to write out a binary search algorithm).

Comment: You've updated your question and I see what you're asking now, answering...

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've updated your question to include that the data will only have 1, 2, or 3 in it: You can simply just recursively check which number you are at in your range:

```
public static int findSum(int[] a, int start, int stop) {
    if (start < 0 || start >= a.length || stop < 0 || stop >= a.length) { //bounds check
        return 0;
    }
    if (start == stop) { //return the number!
        return a[start];
    } else if (a[start] == a[stop]) { //catch for some quick math, return amount of values * the value
        return a[start] * (stop - start + 1);
    } else {
        int mid = start + ((stop - start) >>> 1); //This is the middle point between start and stop
        return findSum(a, start, mid) + findSum(a, mid + 1, stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at this when I get some time